# QWebView library not found

Tags: qt

When i try to add the **QWebFrame library**, i can't find it and the reply is no such file or directory so any idea why is this library not present. I am adding the library as follows:

`#include <QWebFrame>`

The error is caused by this line of code:

`QString content=ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->toPlainText();`

Note that in a previous project i added this library and it was present.
Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect you're missing the following line in your .pro file:

```
QT += webkit webkitwidgets
```

Comment: If that is not enough you also need to append "webkitwidgets".